# Angular multiple ng-selected option not working in edit popup

Tags: typescript, angular-ngselect, angular16

[image]

[image]

TS

```
Pincodes: Array<string> = [];
```

Html

```
 <ng-select [items]="Pincodes" [searchable]="true" [multiple]="true" [(ngModel)]="updateZoneDetails.selectedpincode" bindLabel="pincode" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [placeholder]="'Select Pincodes'"></ng-select>
```

I'm trying to fetch the data in edit option but its not working in Angular. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add `bindValue` like this:

```
 <ng-select [items]="Pincodes" [searchable]="true" [multiple]="true" [(ngModel)]="updateZoneDetails.selectedpincode" bindValue="id"  bindLabel="pincode" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [placeholder]="'Select Pincodes'"></ng-select>
```